# Text Shadow by CSS

Tags: css, shadow

We are using different static images as per year to display.

I want to make it dynamic by adding image without number and adding number. Its looks good except. I tried text-shadow css property but does not give same result like image.

Is it possible to add shadow by css which goes to end of left corner?

[image: anniversary years image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to use multiples text-shadow to achieve this style.

```css
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #087194, 2px 2px 0 #087194, 3px 3px 0 #087194, 4px 4px 0 #087194, 5px 5px 0 #087194;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h462ruey/33/